# TypeError when developing tkinter notepad-like application in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've trying to make a notepad application - here's my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
top=Tk()
top.title('Mypad')
def save(self,s):
    self.s=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt')
    c=open(self.s,'w')
    w=c.write(str(e.get('1.0','end')))
def close():
    top.destroy()
menubar=Menu(top)
file=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
vet=file.add_command(label='Save',command=save)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label='Exit',command=close)
menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=file)
e=Text()
e.pack(ipady=30)
top.config(menu=menubar)
top.mainloop()
```

But when I run it and try to save it it is saying like this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Workspace\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 's'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `filedialog` first. And you don't need `self` here & neither `s` as argument.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
top=Tk()
top.title('Mypad')
def save():
    s=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt')
    c=open(s,'w')
    w=c.write(str(e.get('1.0','end')))
def close():
    top.destroy()
menubar=Menu(top)
file=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
vet=file.add_command(label='Save',command=save)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label='Exit',command=close)
menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=file)
e=Text()
e.pack(ipady=30)
top.config(menu=menubar)
top.mainloop()
```